# Prevent pip in conda environment from using a global install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install a number of packages within a `conda` environment, using `pip`. I installed `pip` within the `conda` environment, as well.

However, a while ago I must have installed some of these packages globally. `pip` is using these global installations, and as a result it is not installing the packages in the `conda` environment and my script does not recognize the imports when I try to import the packages.

Further, I tried using `pip uninstall <package>` outside of a `conda` environment to try to uninstall the global installation. It looked like it was successful, but then I had the same issue where it said the requirement was already satisfied in the global location.

Here is a snippet of the output, within the `conda` environment `streamlit0`:

```
(streamlit0) 17:19:39 ~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/.../Streamlit/theo 
⠠⠵ pip install streamlit openai llama-index nltk
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: streamlit in /Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (1.31.0)
Collecting openai
  Downloading openai-1.11.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting llama-index
  Downloading llama_index-0.9.43-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
Collecting nltk
  Downloading nltk-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.5/1.5 MB 9.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: altair<6,>=4.0 in /Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from streamlit) (5.2.0)
...
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in /Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from openai) (1.3.0)
...
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.6->llama-index)
  Downloading aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.6->llama-index) (23.1.0)
```

How can I 1) get rid of these global installs and 2) only install these packages within this `conda` environment?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just delete the global site-packages altogether?

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install <package>
```

This will install the package in the current environment. If you wish to specify the environment use the `--name` flag.

```
conda install --name myenv scipy
```

This command will install SciPy in the `myenv` environment.

---

If the package isn't available in conda then you should do this.

1. Activate the environment where you want download the package
2. Install your package `pip install <package>` note that you may need to uninstall the package globally
3. Check that the package was installed `conda list` .. If it wasn't then refer to this [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env)

Read more about installing in the environment [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html)

Comment: The problem is that the packages I need aren't available in conda.

Comment: @Adam_G I updated the answer to fit your requirements!